# How can I use bootstrap in react with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, sprockets, reactstrap

I have tried using npm package `reactstrap`.
My components:

```
import { Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError at /dir/xyz
TypeError: require is not a function
```

Comment: Did you installed it with npm ?

Comment: Yes. the package is now in my node_modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `webpacker`-gem is the way to go for react + rails, not sprockets, which is ok for jQuery style JS, but not for complicated ES6-based stacks.

From the README:

> To use Webpacker with React, create a new Rails 5.1+ app using --webpack=react option:
>
> ```
> # Rails 5.1+
> rails new myapp --webpack=react
> ```
>
> (or run `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react` in a existing Rails app already setup with Webpacker).
>
> The installer will add all relevant dependencies using Yarn, changes to the configuration files, and an example React component to your project in app/javascript/packs so that you can experiment with React right away.

Note that you'll be using yarn from then on, instead of npm.

Comment: We are using sprockets for now. But If we don't find any solution, with sprockets, we'll move to webpacker.

Comment: Webpacker deals with a lot of stuff you're kind of required to have and that sprocket simply can't offer: tree shaking (removing all modules not imported by your app); proper babel integration (there is a sprockets-es6 project, but it is out of date). I'm not a huge fan of Webpacker and like the simplicity of Sprockets, but Sprockets is simply not advanced enough for dealing with the mess that comes with modern JS-frameworks.

Comment: Thanks @murb. Now, I used webpacker. It's working with a new app. But when I use this in my existing app, there is an error: `Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript`
and in console `Page not found for: /packs/hello_react-d061dc84049eca53c1a2.js from IP:(127.0.0.1)`

Comment: Is this because webpacker compile assets in public and app/assets directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626905/webpacker-cant-use-public-assets-packs-assets-without-bin-webpack-dev-server