# Webpacker: Can't use public/assets/packs assets without ./bin/webpack-dev-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Rails + Webpacker (for React npm packages).
When I am trying to use any assets, an error occurs:

> Security warning: an embedded  tag on another site requested protected JavaScript

And that's why it doesn't load my assets javascript compiled by webpacker.

It only works if I run `./bin/webpack-dev-server`

How can I load my assets without `./bin/webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: Hmm... did you follow all steps correcty? I've upgraded manually two projects already myself and haven't ran into this issue (but maybe it is a recent change): https://github.com/rails/webpacker#installation

Comment: I had to add `./bin/webpack-dev-server` in Procfile itself. Now, `webpack-dev-server` is running in separte port. I am still not getting, why do we need a separate port for just assets, when we already have them compiled in `public/assets/packs/`

Comment: You shouldn't have to; webpack-dev-server is mainly for auto-reloading etc; typically a reload of the page should rebuild your assets as well if needed; but maybe the webpacker-react config is assuming you actually want goodies like HMR in development and disabled the traditional build on reload. Note this is only for development; in production these should be static assets (haven't used webpacker for React myself)

Comment: Yes it did work in staging and production without webpack-dev-server